# Symfony : should repositories contain only queries to the database?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository

Let's suppose we have 2 methods in a repository :

```
public function findByMonth($month) {
    // ... DQL query to the database
}


public function findByYear($year)
   $year = ... ;
   $result = [];

   for (...) {
       $month = ... ;
       $result[] = $this->findByMonth($month);
   }

   return $result;
}
```

The second method do not execute query to the database. It only calls the first method and create a loop and some logic adjustments.

Should it stays in the `Repository` or should it go in a Service (`Formatter` ? `Manager` ?)

Answer (score 3):

Repository is a pattern which represents an architectural layer that handles communication between the application and data source.
In my opinion you need to move `findByYear` function into a service that call the repository method.

Like this:

```
class YourService 
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(YourRepository $repository)
    {
         $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function findByYear($year)
    {
        $year = ... ;
        $result = [];

        for (...) {
            $month = ... ;
            $result[] = $this->repository->findByMonth($month);
        }

        return $result;
    }   
}
```